# Android Browser Privacy Settings: "Clear cookies" and "clear cache"

Tags: browser, privacy, adobe-flash, stock-browser

I have a couple of questions about privacy and Android phones, though it probably relates to the windows phone as well and welcome the thoughts of any developers.

Do the 'clear cookies' and or 'clear cache' functions actually remove hidden tracking cookies that use either **Flash based cookies** or the **client side storage area** inside the web browser?

If not, how do you delete them without resetting the entire phone?

Answer (score 2):

To reset the Flash based data storage (technically like cookies), you have to wipe the data for the Flash Plugin. Home => Settings => Applications => Manage Applications => Adobe Flash Player => Clear Data.  I would do the same procedure for your browser application, too, if have nothing valuable saved in the browser settings/passwords.

I wish Adobe had provided some form of privacy configuration application as they started to include with latest Flash Plugin for desktops.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the HTML5 client-side storage isn't in either of those locations.

To clear that, you need to go into your browser, press the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button, select, **More**, then **Settings** then scroll right to the bottom where you can see (under the Advanced heading) **Website settings**, now you should be able to see which websites have stored data on your phone (shows as a rectangle that fills up, the more they store), as well as what other permissions you've given websites, like which ones can use your location data.